# CSS Difference in defining fonts in different ways

Tags: html, css, font-family

I have seen many a time user define Fonts in CSS like

```
font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,serif
```

AND

```
 font-family:Times New Roman,Georgia,serif
```

Does defining font in quotes make any difference i have seen this style couple of time.

I would appreciate an expert opening on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [W3 documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp) on that. It says:

**Note: If a font name contains white-space, it must be quoted.**

Answer (score 2):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop

> Font family names must either be given quoted as strings, or unquoted
> as a sequence of one or more identifiers. This means most punctuation
> characters and digits at the start of each token must be escaped in
> unquoted font family names.
>
> Font family names that happen to be the same as a keyword value
> ('inherit', 'serif', 'sans-serif', 'monospace', 'fantasy', and
> 'cursive') must be quoted to prevent confusion with the keywords with
> the same names. The keywords 'initial' and 'default' are reserved for
> future use and must also be quoted when used as font names. UAs must
> not consider these keywords as matching the '' type.

Answer (score 1):

Any font names that are more than one word are often wrapped in quotes, however this is not a requirement.

[Why would font names need quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751412/font-names-with-quotes-what-is-the-right-usage)